# Reassign Cases from one queue to another queue

Tags: soql, case

Could you please help me? I need to reassign Cases from one CaseOwner (Queue1) to another CaseOwner (Queue2), problem is that there are more then 40000 records. How can I do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Apex Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5) to easily download the cases, alter in any spreadsheet program, then update using the app. You could also use dataloader.io or another tool to a similar effect (note: I am not affiliated with any app mentioned, be sure to do product research if you're interested in alternatives).